# Rails Nested Ressources and External Get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, resources, routes, nested

I have a nested ressources and I created an external get to an alternative "Show" view, like that :

```
resources :teams do
  get "alternativeshow"
  resources :teammates
end
```

That gives me this url which is perfect :

```
http://appname.com/teams/:team_id/alternativeshow
```

and call the controller teams#alternativeshow

Inside teams#alternativeshow I want to set @team and @teammates just like in my regular #show

```
def show
 @team = current_crafter.teams.find(params[:id])
 @teammates = @team.teammates
end
```

but I can't figure out how.
When I copy-paste show actions inside alternativeshow I got this error

```
Couldn't find Team without an ID
```

I noticed (without understanding why) in rake routes that :id becomes :team_id so I setted @team like this to make it work:

```
@team = current_crafter.teams.find(params[:team_id])
```

However I can't find how to have my teammates since the ressource is nested inside teams ?
Is "get" the right way to do it ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
resources :teams do
  resources :alternatives, only: [:show]
  resources :teammates
end
```

This should provide the team_id and id params in the alternatives#show

Edit:

instead of a show action for @teammates in your alternatives#show, you'd want to use an index action to be able to get a collection, so you could add an index to the only: [:index, :show] call

than

```
alternativescontroller ...
  def index
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id]
    @teammates = @team.teammates
  end
end
```

All nested resource contollers methods follow this pattern

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

In fact I didn't mention that team has_many teammates. The url only have the card id (:id in crud and :card_id with get). I would like to be able to get all the teammates like "@teammates = @team.teammates" but don't know how to call teammates in controller. I tried resources only show but it renders a url like appname.com/teams/:team_id/alternative/:id.

Comment: Once again, thank you !
It seems logical to use resources for rendering the alternativeshow and I thought about it before using get.
Since I have 4 alternatives views, that means 4 controllers, that's the reason why I wanted to use get. But I think wrong I guess.
If I use resources, It will search for /:id at the end of the url. Since I won't pass it, what is the :id at the end of the url for ?

Comment: This is basic REST practices, a get with an :id will fetch a single resource, you want an index action, a get that fetches a collection, it will not require an :id